# In R, compare vectors of different length to match and replace values

Tags: r, replace, match

Thanks for your help.

I have two data frames. The data frames are of differing lengths. One is a data set that often includes mistakes. Another is a set of corrections. I'm trying to do two things at once with these two data sets. First, I would like to compare three columns of `df1` with three columns in `df2`. This means reading the first row of data in `df1` and seeing if those three variables match any of the rows in `df2` for those three variables, then moving on to row 2, and so on. If a match is found in a row for all three variables, then replace the value in one of the columns in `df1` with a replacement in `df2`. I have included an example below.

```
df1 <- data.frame("FIRM" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), "LOCATION" = c("N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S"), "NAME" = c("Apple", "Blooberry", "Cucumber", "Date", "Egplant", "Fig"))
df2 <- data.frame("FIRM" = c("A", "C"), "LOCATION" = c("S", "N"), "NAME" = c("Blooberry", "Egplant"), "NEW_NAME" = c("Blueberry", "Eggplant"))
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)
```

If there is a row in `df1` that matches against "FIRM", "LOCATION" and "NAME" in `df2`, then I would like to replace the "NAME" in `df1` with "NEW_NAME" in `df2`, such that "Blooberry" and "Egplant" change to "Blueberry" and "Eggplant".

I can do the final replacements using*:

```
df1$NAME[match(df2$NAME, df1$NAME)] <- df2$NEW_NAME[match(df1$NAME[match(df2$NAME, df1$NAME)], df2$NAME)]
```

But this does not include the constraint of the three matches. Also, my code seems unnecessarily complex with the nested match functions. I think I could accomplish this task by subsetting `df2` and using a `for` loop to match rows one by one but I would think that there is a better vectorized method out there.

*I'm aware that inside the brackets of `df2$NEW_NAME[]`, the function calls both elements in that column, but I'm trying to generalize.

Comment: By the way, I have actually gotten around this in the past by pasting the three columns together in both data frames and matching the single column only, but I would really like to find a solution for the problem above.

Comment: If the core of your question is how to match on multiple columns, that has been asked on this site before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6880450/3093387. You could just match on the interaction of the relevant variables.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. I usually do that when importing data but didn't realize you could do that in the `data.frame()` command.

Comment: @josliber It's to match on multiple columns and update one table, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6112260/ I think. C8H's answer extends to multiple columns there, at least. Without the update aspect, it's just generic join FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an *all.x* `merge` (i.e., `LEFT JOIN` in SQL speak) with an `ifelse` conditional comparing *NAME* and *NEW_NAME*.

Below, `transform` allows same line column assignment and the bracketed sequence at end keeps first three columns.

```
mdf <- transform(merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE),NAME=ifelse(is.na(NEW_NAME),NAME,NEW_NAME))[1:3]
mdf
#   FIRM LOCATION      NAME
# 1    A        N     Apple
# 2    A        S Blueberry
# 3    B        N  Cucumber
# 4    B        S      Date
# 5    C        N  Eggplant
# 6    C        S       Fig
```

Comment: Instead of `1:3`, I'd do `names(df1)` at the end.

Comment: It took me a bit more of researching your answer to see that it actually did everything I asked. I've never used a SQL database so I am not familiar with the intricacies of database joins and did not realize that is what `merge()` actually does. So it appears that the merge function itself does the matching for all same-named columns all on its own! That's a revelation to me. Thanks!

Comment: Haha...Awesome! Glad to help with solution and eureka moment. Happy coding!