# Find location in first dataframe of matching rows in two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes which share some matching coordinates. I want to find the location in xygrid of the rows that match in the two dataframes.

```
xygrid <- data.frame("x" = c(-175, -165, -155, -145, -135, -125, -115), "y" = c(85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85))

xygrid2 <- data.frame("x" = c(-165, -145), "y" = c(85, 85))

> xygrid
     x  y
1 -175 85
2 -165 85
3 -155 85
4 -145 85
5 -135 85
6 -125 85
7 -115 85

> xygrid2
     x  y
1 -165 85
2 -145 85

#Ideal output
> output
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

#So that I can extract the location
>   xygrid[output,]
     x  y
2 -165 85
4 -145 85
```

Comment: Is it important that you know the indices of the matching rows (2, 4), or is it sufficient just to extract them? If the latter you could use `dplyr::inner_join(xygrid, xygrid2)`, or `merge`.

Comment: I need to know the indices - otherwise I would have gone for one of those options yes! :)

Comment: [The accepted, or the second (higher voted) answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880450/match-two-columns-with-two-other-columns) should help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The accepted answer won't work in my case because my actual dataset will make far too large a matrix, and the second answer appears to only work when the vectors are the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` the columns and find them in other dataframe using `%in%`

```
do.call(paste, c(xygrid, sep = '-')) %in% do.call(paste, c(xygrid2, sep = '-'))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

An admittedly simple answer:

```
library(dplyr)
xygrid %>% 
  left_join(xygrid2 %>% mutate(output = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(is.na(output), FALSE, output))
```

Add `%>% pull(output)` at the end if what you want is the vector form.